# Replace Bad Words from Input Multiple Choice of Words

Tags: javascript, regex, input

How would I amend this script to check a list of words and regex them.

Lets say I had a list of swear words, and I wanted this code below to change any 1 of them, how would I alter the below code?

At the moment i have it changing just the 1 word, but i want It to do more words.

```
<script>
var titleB = document.getElementbyid('inputvalue');

var regex= /fuck/gi;
titleB.value=titleB.value.replace(regex, "fudge");      

</script>
```

Comment: I suggest creating an object where the key is the word you want to replace and the value is the word to replace it with.

Comment: Replace with what? Is there a different replacement for each bad word? Or is it the same replacement for all bad words? (This makes a difference).

Comment: Use the logical or operator ? https://regex101.com/r/7cmmWt/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to just add multiple words in regex. For example,if you want to replace two words "abc" and "gef", you can use the below regex:

```
/abc|gef/gi
```

Please find the console output below:

```
>> var data = "abc d abc gef a";
undefined
>> data
"abc d abc gef a"
>> var regex = /abc|gef/gi;
undefined
>> data.replace(regex,"fudge");
"fudge d fudge fudge a"
```

Another example as discussed in comments :

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sort of, i just gotta think about what your telling me lol  maybe like this .     var regex = /fudgea|fudgeb/gi;    data.replace(regex,"fudgea fudgeb")

Comment: and i can only add 2 words to the regex for some reason , anymore and they dont highlight    /1word/2word/gi   - if i do  /1/2/3/gi  it wont work

Comment: @MelissaHicking There is some confusion you have, you can have as many bad words as you have in the list in regex variable and in replace you can replace it with mask word, that may be fudge or **** or whatever you want. Hope that makes senses

Comment: aaahhh, thats a good idea, il try that

Comment: yes but im having trouble coding it .. heres what iv got, NOT WORKING lol

Comment: @MelissaHicking you are adding '/' but you need to add '|' which means OR in regex. I have added another example above.

Comment: stuck on how to code the regex bit

Comment: yes iv gotta try it until i find the right method..

Comment: @MelissaHicking Hope the other example I shared will help you in my answer just replace word1,word2,word3 with the words you have in your list.